# Filter NSArray with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I want to filter an array of `User` objects (`User` has `fullname`, `user_id` and some more attributes..) according to `firstName` or `lastName` that begin with some string.
I know how to filter according to one condition:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", word];
NSArray* resArr = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

this will give me all the users that has a firstName that starts with "word".
But what if I want all the users that has a firstName or lastName that start with "word"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the class `NSCompoundPredicate` to create compound predicates.

```
NSPredicate *firstNamePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", word];
NSPredicate *lastNamePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", word];

NSArray *predicates = @[firstNamePred, lastNamePred];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

NSArray* resArr = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

this is one way that I like doing.

Or you can do ...

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ OR lastName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", word, word];
NSArray* resArr = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

either will work.

Comment: for some reason using Compound predicate does not work for me. But using the subPredicates individually works. Any idea what could be going on.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName BEGINSWITH %@ OR lastName BEGINSWITH %@", word, word];
NSArray* resArr = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```