# Filter an array with a keyword

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I just want to filter an NSMutableArray of custom objects with a keyword entered by the user.
Example: when the user enters "a" letter, I want to output all objects where the displayName contains the letter "a".
For that I did like that:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"display_name CONTAINS[cd] %@", textField.text];
NSArray *filtered = [[self.contacts allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The problem is that I have to input the whole display_name to get a result, not just a letter.
Example: if there is "Abraham", "Alexander", "James", and you tap "j", I want to output the object where it's property name is "James", and don't have to enter the WHOLE "James" word to get it.
There is surely a problem with my predicate, thank you for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter NSArray with NSPredicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817340/filter-nsarray-with-nspredicate)

Comment: @BergQuester: I already read that answer, and I did not find a solution for my problem on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to this is to use wildcards.  ***** marks in the argument. ie:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"display_name LIKE[cd] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*", textField.text]];
```